# An example for a continuous, monotone, quasi concave function?

Tags: calculus

Can anybody give me an example for a continuous, monotone, and quasi concave function that is **not** concave?

Answer (score 0):

## Continuous

Has a value everywhere.

## Monotone

**(x <= y) => (f(x) <= f(y))**

or

**(x <= y) => (f(x) >= f(y))**

## Concave

f'(x) is monotonically decreasing. If f'(x) is constant on an interval [a, b] where a <> b, then f is not strictly concave.

## The construction of an example

Take the logarithm as a starting point. It is, continuous monotonically (on the realm of positive real numbers) increasing, quasiconcave AND concave. Not quite the result we expect yet, but pretty close to it:

**ln'(x) = 1/x**

ln(1) = 0

now, let's define a function as follows:

**f(x) = ln(x), if x < 1 or x > 2**

**f(1), if 1 <= x <= 2**